# Worker / Integrator Classes Distinction

Tags: unit-testing, oop, tdd

In [this article by Jakub Holý](http://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/principles-for-creating-maintainable-and-evolvable-tests/) on writing maintainable and evolvable tests, the author shares his experience of a course lectured by Kent Beck and that when designing a part of the system Kent would divide the classes into workers (containing logic and fully unit-tested) and integrators (very little logic, tested by integration tests).

[image]

Reading this I remembered an [article by John Sonmez](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/01/23/back-to-basics-unit-testing-without-mocks/) that expressed the very same idea:

> What I mean by this is that our goal should be to refactor or write our code in such a way that logic is grouped into classes that only depend on primitive types and data classes, not other classes that contain logic.
>
> This of course is not fully achievable, because something will have to tie all of these logic containing classes together.  We we need these tie-together classes, but if we can make their job to simply execute commands and tie other classes together, we can feel pretty confident in not unit testing them, and we make our job a whole lot easier.

This sounds like very reasonable advice to me, but I could not find any other resources on the idea, partly because I have no idea what to search for.

Does this idea / pattern have a name?

**EDIT** Just found another great [article by Steven Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/11/04/selective-unit-testing-costs-and-benefits/) that describes the same idea. He speaks of **Algorithms** and **Coordinators** which are terms that I like a lot.

Comment: You might get better answers at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ But to me this would be covered by SOLID, especially the parts around single responsibility. Looking at the examples John provided it doesn't look like a change of _pattern_, it looks like going from seriously bad code, to a bit better.

Comment: It's not so much about single responsiblity but about that distinction between algorithms / workers and coordinators / integrators and the effect of this distinction on testing strategies that I am interested in. For me, the question is clearly a programming question so I asked it on SO.

Comment: It was only an advice about where to post it simply because the people over at programmers tend to be a bit more theoretically oriented and would provide more convered result. But that last article hints better at what you are looking for. I did a simple google for "test what needs to be tested" (which I would say is a strategy) and came up with lots of answers and theories around this. Most of them from blogs, but several from programmers.

Comment: So if I understand your question right my answer has to be; stick to SOLID and "test what needs to be tested".

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what ["Ports & Adapters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) (also known as the Hexagonal Architecture) is about.

It structures you business code into "Domain" which contains your use case independent business logic (domain entities) and "Application" which contains your use case specific business logic (application services).

In addition you have "Adapters" which implement the technical code, like integration with other services, databases, frameworks, etc.

"Ports" are the abstract declarations that adapters implement (i.e. The interface for a repository is a port, the implementation of that interface is the adapter)

The application services are, what other approaches call "Coordinator", "Interactors", or "Control Objects" (not to be confused with "Controllers").

The "Domain Entities" are what other approaches call "Algorithms" or, well, "Entities".

Kent Becks "Workers" are a combination of "Application" and "Domain", while his "Integrators" are "Adapters" in P&A speak.

(don't confuse domain entities with database entities)